# google apps website ownership verification problem

Tags: google-workspace, error

I own the website www.vargbloom.com
I have uploaded the verification page in my website

http://vargbloom.com/googleba3ecd16361333b2.html

but still it shows an error like
We weren't able to verify your site: http://vargbloom.com/

can anyone help

Comment: How long has it been? This is generally taken care of pretty quickly after you click the confirm button(you did, right?), but I've seen it take a couple hours on rare occasion. Also, is that the *exact* error message? If not, go back and paste that here; approximations won't help anyone.

Comment: It's been a while since the question was asked, but the above link to the verification file throws a 404.

Comment: It works fine now, I uploaded a new file and changed the hosting to godaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you uploaded the right html file. If you have multiple google accounts upload file for that particular account.

You can also try alternative verifying methods like TXT, CNAME Etc.

Gook Luck

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that some .htaccess file is blocking the read access for that file.
I faced a similar problem, when the site was actually compromised and the .htaccess was modified.